# Ionic 4 input keyboard scrolls up contents

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

hope you will be fine. I need some help. I am using ion-textarea in my ionic project and below that I have some buttons. When I build the app and test on android it looks perfect. When I tap on ion-textarea and simply close keyboad without typing anything it works fine but when I tap on ion-textarea and start typing something and then close the keyboard, the content below the ion-textarea scrollls up and does not go down.Here is the screenshot of the error:
[image]

Looking forward to see your response, thanks!

Comment: I wonder how you fixed this...

Answer (score 0):

This issue still seems to persist : https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/issues/155

Since this issue seems to be caused by the keyboard on iOS, the easier fix would be to use a different [keyboard plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard)  as well as upgrade to the latest version of [cordova-ios](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/01/cordova-ios-release-6.0.0.html).